# validate form data before button onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html, validation, onclick

I am really stuck on this one.

I have a form which sends an email, to do so the input has to be validated. I got some working method to validate the input, the mail() function also works, same with the delete and send button.

My trouble is now that if you click the send button, it should
 **first validate the data**(or print error on invalide)
 and then
 **show the confirm popup If user really want to send the mail**.
 I have no clue how to accomplish that.

below my snippets

assigning the form values to variables and validating the input (I will only show you the email validation, else the snipped is too long and all validations work just fine)

```
<?php

ini_set("display_errors", "off");


$email = "";
$betreff = "";
$message = "";
$urgend = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$email = validateEmail($_POST["email"]);
$betreff = validateBetreff($_POST["betreff"]);
$message = validateMessage($_POST["message"]);

if ($urgend = $_POST["urgend"]) {
    $urgend = "dringend";
} else {
    $urgend = "nicht dringend";
}
}

function validateEmail($email)
{

if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

    $error = '<p style="color:red; text-align:center"><strong>Ung&uumlltige email formatierung!</strong><br>Beispiel f&uumlr eine g&uumlltige Email: abc@beispiel.de<br></p>';
    echo $error;

} else {

    return $email;
}

}
```

and my "send" Button

```
 <button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="if(!window.confirm('Jetzt senden?')) return false;">
    Senden
</button>
```

Again my goal:

**1st validate the input**
**2nd confirmation Popup**
**3rd try send the mail**

what it currently does:

**1st confirmation Popup**
**2nd validate the input**
**3rd try send the mail**

Comment: Your current validation of the data happens server-side, so you could only output the confirmation popup on the resulting page. You would need to switch this to client-side validation or to submitting the data for validation via AJAX first, if you want to have that confirmation popup on the same page.

Comment: @misorude what would client-side validation be like?

Comment: That’s way too broad of a question in general. As @onovikov just suggested in their answer, if you only need to ensure that a valid e-mail address was used, you can use the HTML5 `email` field type, then you get the validation for that particular aspect “build-in” already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this below code

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" id="req_form" method="POST">
<p>Your name: <input type="text" name="email_address" id="email_address" value="" /></p>
<button type="button" name="submit" value="submit" onclick="Process_form();">Senden</button>
</form>
</body>
</html>




<script>

function Process_form()
{

    if($("#email_address").val()=='')
    {
        alert('Enter Email');
    }
    else
    {
        var vali = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
        if (vali.test($("#email_address")) == false) 
        {
            alert('Invalid Email Address');

        }
        else
        {
            var r = confirm("Press a button!");
            if (r == true) {
                $( "#req_form" ).submit();
            } 
        }
    }

}
</script>
```

Comment: I tried this, but it would only check if the field is empty or not, it is not checking for valide email...

Comment: I really do apprecheate your effort and would love to accept it as the answer but I tried it with abc@example.com and it would return invalid :(

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use browser-based field validation.
To do this, it is enough to change the type of the field in which you accept the email (provided that you only need the support of modern browsers)

```
<input type = "email" name = "email" placeholder = "E-Mail" />
```

But a more beautiful solution would be to use Ajax.